# Email Sending Integration Test

Tags: java, spring, email, integration-testing

Please help me to write an integration test for email sending, that inreal  sends email.

```
public interface MailSenderService {

void sendEmail(String to, String from, String subject, String body); }
```

The Mail sender class

```
@Service
public class MailSenderServiceImpl implements MailSenderService {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailSenderServiceImpl.class);

@Autowired
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

@Autowired
Configuration freemarkerConfiguration;

private SimpleMailMessage composeMail(String to, String from, String subject, String body) {
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
    message.setFrom(from);
    message.setTo(to);
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(body);
    return message;
}

@Override
public void sendEmail(String to, String from, String subject, String body) {
    sendMessage(composeMail(to, from, subject, body));
}

@Async
private void sendMessage(SimpleMailMessage message) {
    Assert.notNull(javaMailSender, "Email Sender must not be null");
    javaMailSender.send(message);
}}
```

And finally here is an integration test, which doesn't pass:

```
public class MailSenderServiceIT extends BaseServiceIntegrationTest {

@Autowired
private MailSenderService mailSenderService;

@Test
public void sendEmail() {
    mailSenderService.sendEmail("test1@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com", "Test Subject",
            "Test Body");
    flushAndClear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to know how is configure your JavaMailSender. If you wanna send email in your integrations tests, you need to configure JavaMailSender to use a local configuration. By example localhost:5555 :

```
JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
javaMailSender.setHost("localhost");
javaMailSender.setPort(5555);
```

Then, you can create a server SMTP by using the library [subethasmtp](https://github.com/voodoodyne/subethasmtp) directly in your test. I personnaly create a Junit Rule to do that :

```
public class SMTPServerRule extends ExternalResource {

    private Wiser wiser;
    private String hostname;
    private int port;

    public SMTPServerRule() {
        this(25);
    }

    public SMTPServerRule(int port) {
        this("localhost", port);
    }

    public SMTPServerRule(String hostname, int port) {
        this.hostname = hostname;
        this.port = port;
    }


    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
        super.before();

        wiser = new Wiser(port);
        wiser.setHostname(hostname);
        wiser.start();
    }

    public List<WiserMessage> getMessages() {
        return wiser.getMessages();
    }

    @Override
    protected void after() {
        super.after();
        wiser.stop();
    }
}
```

So, You can do something like that in your integration test :

```
@Rule
public SMTPServerRule smtpServerRule = new SMTPServerRule("localhost", 5555);

@Test
public void sendEmail() {
    mailSenderService.sendEmail("test1@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com", "Test Subject", "Test Body");
    flushAndClear();

    List<WiserMessage> messages smtpServerRule.getMessages();
}
```

Comment: I use these properties for mail sending:
smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
smtp.port=587
smtp.username=example@gmail.com
smtp.password=aaa12345678$

Comment: Running test I get MailAuthenticationException